# How does Undersore's _.now work?

Tags: javascript, browser, underscore.js, v8, native-code

It doesn't look like it is written in JavaScript.

if you type `_now` in the console, you only get

```
function now() { [native code] }
```

You usually only get that when you try to look at some built-in method where the inner-workings are invisible to the browser.

```
setTimeout
=>function setTimeout() { [native code] }
```

Has `_.now` done something with "native code" of the JavaScript engine?

Comment: It probably just uses the native function if it exist. Otherwise it provides an implementation for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default [`_.now`](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/1.9.1/underscore.js#L1463-L1465) is just [`Date.now`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now), except in environments that do not support it. Where `Date.now` isn't supported `_.now` will use this implementation instead (same goes for lodash)

```
_.now = function() {
   return (new Date()).getTime()
};
```

As your browser supports `Date.now`, `_.now` is just a proxy to the native implementation

---

Note: you can also make any of your functions appear as native in console by calling using `Function.prototype.bind`

```
function foo() {console.log('bar');}
var bar = foo.bind(null);

console.log(bar);
// => function () { [native code] }
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the underscore source code:

```
_.now = Date.now || function() {
  return new Date().getTime();
};
```

This means that it will use `Date.now()` if it exists, which is an internal function. Otherwise it will use `new Date().getTime()`, which is supported by all JavaScript engines.

Comment: Ah, I gotcha. And because my browser supports the first with native functionality, all I see when look in the console is the `[native code]`. I had expected to see the actual function. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

It returns an integer timestamp for the current time. Useful for implementing timing/animation functions.

`_.now();
=> 1392066795351`

Comment: Yeah I know what it does. This doesn't address the question. Thanks the same.